# ASP.NET CORE API 3.0 HTTP POST not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am very new to ASP.NET CORE API 3.0.
So far HTTPGET is working , now HTTPPOST api not working. Breakpoint not triggering

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
 [ApiController]

[HttpPost, Route("LeadCreation")]
public  IActionResult LeadCreation([FromBody]string XML)
```

Comment: which is the route you are using for the post?, can you paste the whole url?

Comment: https://localhost:5001/api/sap/LeadCreation

Comment: i just need to trigger to make sure it works

Comment: your controller is named SAPController?, try to put the whole definition of your controller on your question please

Comment: [HttpPost]
        [Route("LeadCreation")]
        public IActionResult Postt([FromHeader] string XML)
        {
           
         }

Comment: how to call this in postman

Comment: i tried break point not hitting on the post man

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**To debug this problem**

**Root Cause**

Sometimes, the asp.net binder cannot convert the htmlbody. When that happens the end point is never hit.

**Make a Temporary Change to the input type for debug**

You can change the parameter type to dynamic (for debugging only). This will allow you to see if the endpoint is hit. If it is, you have to change the model class to match json.

**Double Check Routes**

If nothing happened, then it's a routing issue. Here's how routing works at endpoint.

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET /api/test/3
    [HttpGet("{id:customName}")]
    public IActionResult Get(string id)
    {
        return ControllerContext.MyDisplayRouteInfo(id);
    }

    // GET /api/test/my/3
    [HttpGet("my/{id:customName}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        return ControllerContext.MyDisplayRouteInfo(id);
    }
}
```

Finally if nothing works try looking into the Server Side Model State.

Comment: Can you give some sample for how do an Post Method with routing

Comment: this should be a route issue, bindings works by default with the string parameter, if you want to be more sure you can use a routing constraint for that like {"/xml:string"}